# Create a new instance in MEF

Tags: vb.net, mef

I am using MEF for Plug-in, I made one class `PluginManager` which has propety

```
<ImportMany()>

Public Property Plugins() As Lazy(Of IPlugin, IPluginExport)()
```

Now want to create a new instance of when i query from plugins,

I have already set PartCreationpolicy as Nonshared, but still its not working.

What is solution for it?

Comment: I Found solution to do that, In GetPlugin(Name) function i set Plugins value again. Plugins=Container.GetExports(Of T,TMetadata). Now i am getting a new instance each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Lazy<T,TMetadata>` type (like its `Lazy<T>` counterpart provides of deferred instantiation (e.g. lazy loading). Essentially, the first time the `Value` property is called, it calls a delegated function which grabs the export from the container, composes it and returns its value. Any subsequent call to the `Value` property will return the same value. Because of this, `PartCreationPolicy` is less relevant, because although that still matters at the container level, the lazy instance will only hold onto the same value.

You're solution to use `GetExports` is one method of ensuring the `PartCreationPolicy` is observed, but you have to rely on the fact that the correct `CreationPolicy` must be applied to the type.

What you could consider is using factories instead of your plugin types. There are two ways of doing this, you could use `ExportFactory<T, TMetadata>` which allows you to spin up new instances each time (this is included in the Silverlight variant of MEF, but [Glenn Block also released it for .NET 4.0 [@ his SkyDrive - Composition.Initialization.Desktop](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=f8b2fd72406fb218&id=F8B2FD72406FB218!181)]).

With export factory, you could change your imports to:

```
<ImportMany()>
Public Property PluginFactories() As ExportFactory(Of IPlugin, IPluginExport)()
```

And grab the `ExportLifetimeContext<T>.Value` property return through `CreateExport()`.

The other way you could do it, is if you define another contract, let's call it `IPluginFactory`, which could look like:

```
Public Interface IPluginFactory

  Function CreateInstance() As IPlugin

End Interface

<Export(GetType(IPluginFactory))>
Public Class TestPluginFactory Implements IPluginFactory

  Public Function CreateInstance() As IPlugin 
    Implements IPluginFactory.CreateInstance

    Return New TestPlugin()
  End Function

End Class
```

(Sorry if the syntax isn't quite right, I don't usually do VB).

Now, you could change your import to be:

```
<ImportMany()>
Pulic Property PluginFactories(Of IPlugin, IPluginExport)()
```

...and grab your IPluginFactory instance, then create your `IPlugin` instance by calling the factory's `CreateInstance` method. The other thing you need to consider, is that if your `IPlugin` instance requires composing itself (to satisfy it's own part imports), you need to compose this with your container. To that end, what might be nice, is if your export your container instance, that way you could import it via your factory constructor:

```
Dim container As New CompositionContainer(....)
AttributedModelServices.ComposeExportedValue(container, container)

<Export(GetType(IPluginFactory))>
Public Class TestPluginFactory Implements IPluginFactory

  Private _container As CompositionContainer

  <ImportingConstructor()>
  Public Sub New(container As CompositionContainer)
      _container = container
  End Sub

  Public Function CreateInstance() As IPlugin
    Implements IPluginFactory.CreateInstance

    Dim instance As New TestPlugin()
    AttributedModelServices.ComposeParts(_container, instance)

    Return instance
  End Function

End Class
```

My preference would be to use `ExportFactory` itself, as you don't really have to pass around a container instance, and you get the benefits of automatic instance composition when you grab the part from the factory, but if you want absolute fine grained control over how the plugin instance is created, you can (as shown above) create quite a simple factory.

Whether or not it is right to be passing the container around is another question you'd need to ask, as it does make your factories explicitly dependent on `CompositionContainer`, and thus might make testing it a little more complicated.

What I hope you see, is that with MEF there are a myriad of ways you could solve the same problem, you just have to decide what fits better into your design.